# Arrays >>> name of fruits

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
EditText fruits;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    addListenerButton();
}

private void addListenerButton() {
    fruits=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(fruits.getText().toString().equals("orange")||fruits.getText().toString().equals("aple")||fruits.getText().toString().equals("grape")){
                Intent clicked=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(clicked);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
if(fruits.getText().toString().equals("orange")||fruits.getText().toString().equals("aple")||fruits.getText().toString().equals("grape"))
```

Help me, i want to make 100 name of fruits: can you make this easier. I expect you help me using array list. Thanks alot!

Comment: you can use for loop and compare your value in it

Comment: use ArrayList#contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] terms = {"orange", "apple", "grape"};
if (Arrays.asList(terms).contains(fruits.getText().toString())) {
   // start your activity
}
```